# How to keep the HoloLens On when plugged in

Tags: hololens

I have a HoloLens, and I want to interact with the API's.  Unfortunatetly, it keeps going into standby mode, even when plugged in.  This means I have to wear the HoloLens like a hat to keep it on.  Even though I'm not trying to physically use it.

Is there anyway to keep it out of standby mode when it is plugged in?

Answer (score 4):

You can set the behavior when plugged if you enter the Device Portal (enter the IP of your device in a web browser).

[image]

Comment: However, I edited the HTML in Chrome Inspector, and added an option with the value of 0 (as that is often the "Never" value) and it did save it.  Also, in the last 5 minutes, it hasn't shut itself off while resting (plugged in).

Comment: Stayed up for 2 hours with the Hack.

Comment: Great finding @DanVioletSagmiller!

Comment: been running overnight succesfully.  noted charging is INCREDIBLY SLOW like this...

Comment: WARNING! SIGNIFICANT RISK:  So having tried this for a while, I found a bad situation - While on, it uses enough power that charging had no effect.  I.e. it continues to drain power VERY SLOWLY.  Once it gets low enough, as I found, it shuts its self down.  But once the power got back over 3 or 5%, it would turn itself back on, then start draining power and shut off again.   - - - this created a cycle that kept it on for less than a minute.  It took me about 5 tries to get in and change the power settings, because it kept shutting itself off before I could finish it.